# prove that the matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{\tilde w_1,...,\tilde w_n\}$
 be a linearly independent set in $\mathbb{R}^n$
 and let 
 $\{\tilde v_1,...,\tilde v_n\}$
denote the
orthonormal basis obtained by performing the Gram-Schmidt procedure on 
$\{\tilde w_1,...,\tilde w_n\}$
(which is normalized).

Prove that the matrix $T$ deﬁned by
$t_{ij} = \langle \tilde w_j, \tilde v_i \rangle \quad \forall 1 \leq i, j \leq n$
is invertible.

Comment: How is $T$ defined? What inner product do you mean?

Comment: I edited your question, please make sure that I didn't change the meaning.
@dgrasines517, I think we can assume the standard scalar product, i.e. $\langle u,v\rangle = \sum u_iv_i$

Answer (score 1):

I'll drop the tilde. Gram-Schmidt creates an orthonormal basis, thus we know that the matrix
\begin{align}
Q = \Bigl( v_1 |...|v_n\Bigr)
\end{align}
is orthonormal.

The $w_j$ are linearly independent, thus the matrix
\begin{align}
W=\Bigl(w_1|...|w_n\Bigr)
\end{align}
is invertible.

$t_{ij}$ is $\langle w_i,v_j\rangle$ and thus $T=W\cdot Q$

Then $\det(T)=\det(W\cdot Q)=\det(W)\cdot \det(Q) =\det(W)\cdot 1 \not =0$ since $W$ is invertible and $Q$ orthonormal. Thus, $T$ is invertible.